# Windows 10 version 1703 Data Execution Prevention blocking EXE

Tags: windows, windows-10, dep

Under Windows 10 1703 with DEP set to protect essential Windows programs and services only, this particular EXE will crash (on a very few machines) and a corresponding event ID 1000 will be present in the application log, which is a DEP event.

Adding it to the exclusion list doesn't work.

The only thing that *does* work is disabling DEP completely using BCDEDIT.

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the executable in question invoked another executable
that was not exempt from DEP. Examine carefully the details in Event Viewer.

You could use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)
to monitor its execution and see what it does.

For more information see the article
[Understanding Process Monitor](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/sysinternals-pro/lesson4/all/).

Comment: It does but excluding them both in DEP has no effect. However creating an EMET mitigation rule explicitly disabling all mitigations works.